# Identifier has been declared

Tags: javascript, console.log

since I am a beginner can't know what is happening there. could you help/explain to me what is happening?

It works with all the properties except the "location", it says:

`property has been declared`

```js
'use strict';

const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firence, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
  hello_kitty: function (two, three) {
    return [this.starterMenu[two], this.mainMenu[three]];
  },
};


const {location} = restaurant;
console.log(location);
```

Comment: If you did this in the `window` scope, there is [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Note you can still use destructuring you just need to alias your `location` property as something not reserved `const {location:locn} = restaurant;` (Now have a variable `locn` with your valuie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this code in the browser's console it is natural to get this error as location is a reserved name for the Location Object, an object that contains information about the current page URL.

See : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your console tells: can't assign the `location` property into a new variable because it **has been declared before**.

this happened because your Javascript run in a environment (browser) and this environment has some variables and methods on it.

you can see this via:

```
console.log(window)
```

the result would be:

```
Window {0: global, window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
```

as you see, location is a predefined property that exists in your window object, so declaring new `location` property in the `global scope` was the cause of the issue.

if you are familiar with the `scopes` in Javascript, you can simply wrap your code snippet into a function to make it work properly:

```js
'use strict';

function logLocation(){
   const restaurant = {
      name: 'Classico Italiano',
      location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firence, Italy',
      categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
      starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
      mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
      hello_kitty: function (two, three) {
        return [this.starterMenu[two], this.mainMenu[three]];
      },
  };


  const {location} = restaurant;
  console.log(location);
}

logLocation()
```